# Magento Product View does not work

Tags: magento, view, product

I made a product import from ZenCart to Magento with Cart2Cart. Now, if I want to open a product view over the category block it says "The page you requested was not found......". This, however, is only the case for 2 products. If I open the not-working product over the "Recently viewed" block, it will show up. The problem is the url, there are missing parts in it, and I don't know how to fix it.

Site: http://www.ihnkenrollen.de/

Opened from category block: http://www.ihnkenrollen.de//r-ckenlochbefestigung/testproduct.html

Opened from recently watched: http://www.ihnkenrollen.de/testproduct.html

Thanks!

Comment: please re-index one time and check, if problem still there let me know...

Comment: if you mean clear cache with re-index, then yeah, i already did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Then use this also,

goto admin>system>configuration and do this, then use this....

[image]

clear cache with re-index then check.

Thanks
Ravi

[image]

Comment: if i do that, my category block disappears

Comment: can you share with me you admin username or pass?

Comment: i'm not allowed to do that because i'm just editing the site, it's not my own.

Comment: i still don't know what you mean by re-indexing?

Comment: maybe i'm just too stupid to see it :) but i can't find any index management in system configuratuin

Comment: it means you don't have full access of admin give by Client...because i'ts be show in same location....

Comment: i should have full access, under which category is it? so i can search more precise

Comment: well you told me to check under configuration, but it's not, ill try it out